# PHP, displaying thai character from a sql database

Tags: php, sql, special-characters

Inside a sql data database I have some filed with Thai character.
When I'm querying the database to display these name, some character are displaying, but some are not, question marque instead of the character.

Any idea what should I do to display the whole name?

So far I added this in my html:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=windows-874">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-language" CONTENT="th">
```

Comment: Best piece of advice I ever received: **Use UTF-8 everywhere**. This includes the db, the db access layer (PDO/mysqli) and the html.

Comment: what do you mean? how are you using it please?

Comment: What character encoding are you using for the database? I'd recommend setting it to UTF-8, since it will be available for all languages.

Comment: yes it's already set to UTF-8, I have this header:
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');

Comment: There are mainly, but not only, 3 places to check for the encoding: the db, the PDO/mysqli access and the html. And they should have the same charset, either UTF-8 or whichever charset you are using (or compatible ones).

Comment: ok thanks, I think I solved my issue, I was using substr to troncat the name, now I'm using mb_substr($name, 0, 25, 'UTF-8') and it seems to work

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through